# How open folder and past text in search box

Tags: c#, windows, directory

I open folder with

```
Process.Start(@"C:\temp")
```

How can I paste some text in [search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDf6D.png) in opened folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetFiles() method, which accepts the file name as a Path, and contains an overload that allows for recursive searching using a SearchOptions enum.

[GetFiles() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
    Process.Start(@"search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Temp&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A" + "SomeText" + "&crumb=location:C%3A%5CTemp")
```